# Java ODBC character limit issue

Tags: java, sql, odbc, character-limit

I need to use an INSERT INTO statement in java. I have the connection and everything set up. The issue I have is that the statement is exceeding the character limit. Is there a possible way that I can edit a column at a time in a single row, through a loop of some sort?

Comment: What you mean 'exceeding the character limit'? Could you show code and stacktrace?

Comment: Also, the JDBC-ODBC bridge has been removed from Java as of version 8; how (exactly) are you connecting to your datasource?